# Create a male/female variable for an equation

Tags: python

I’m developing a BMI and fat percentage calculator for a school project. I took a model with a ready-made GUI and made the necessary adjustments, but I’m stuck in the equation to calculate the fat percentage.

This is my full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def fazer_reset():
    idade_tf.delete(0, 'end')
    altura_tf.delete(0, 'end')
    peso_tf.delete(0, 'end')


def calcular_imc():
    kg = int(peso_tf.get())
    m = int(altura_tf.get()) / 100
    imc = kg / (m * m)
    imc = round(imc, 1)
    indice_de_imc(imc)


def indice_de_imc(imc):
    if imc < 18.5:
        messagebox.showinfo('IMC', f'IMC = {imc} está Abaixo do peso')
    elif (imc > 18.5) and (imc < 24.9):
        messagebox.showinfo('IMC', f'IMC = {imc} está Normal')
    elif (imc > 24.9) and (imc < 29.9):
        messagebox.showinfo('IMC', f'IMC = {imc} está Acima do peso')
    elif (imc > 29.9):
        messagebox.showinfo('IMC', f'IMC = {imc} está Obeso')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('IMC', 'algo deu errado!')


def calcular_gordura():
    idade = int(idade_tf.get())
    kg = int(peso_tf.get())
    m = int(altura_tf.get()) / 100
    imc = kg / (m * m)
    imc = round(imc, 1)
    gordura = (1.2*imc)+(0.23*idade)-(10.8*sexo)-5.4
    gordura = round(gordura, 1)
    percentual_de_gordura(gordura)

def percentual_de_gordura(gordura):
    messagebox.showinfo('Percentual de Gordura', f'O percentual de gordura é de {gordura} %')


ws = Tk()
ws.title('Calculadora de IMC, Percentual de Gordura e Massa Corporal')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws.config(bg='#686e70')

var = IntVar()

frame = Frame(
    ws,
    padx=10,
    pady=10
)
frame.pack(expand=True)

idade_lb = Label(
    frame,
    text="Idade"
)
idade_lb.grid(row=1, column=1)

idade_tf = Entry(
    frame,
)
idade_tf.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=5)

sexo_lb = Label(
    frame,
    text='Sexo'
)
sexo_lb.grid(row=2, column=1)

frame2 = Frame(
    frame
)
frame2.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=5)

masculino_rb = Radiobutton(
    frame2,
    text='Masculino',
    variable=var,
    value=1
)
masculino_rb.pack(side=LEFT)

feminino_rb = Radiobutton(
    frame2,
    text='Feminino',
    variable=var,
    value=0
)
feminino_rb.pack(side=RIGHT)

altura_lb = Label(
    frame,
    text="Altura (cm)  "
)
altura_lb.grid(row=3, column=1)

peso_lb = Label(
    frame,
    text="Peso (kg)  ",

)
peso_lb.grid(row=4, column=1)

altura_tf = Entry(
    frame,
)
altura_tf.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=5)

peso_tf = Entry(
    frame,
)
peso_tf.grid(row=4, column=2, pady=5)

frame3 = Frame(
    frame
)
frame3.grid(row=5, columnspan=3, pady=10)

imc_btn = Button(
    frame3,
    text='IMC',
    command=calcular_imc
)
imc_btn.pack(side=LEFT)

gordura_btn = Button(
    frame3,
    text='Gordura',
    command=calcular_gordura
)
gordura_btn.pack(side=LEFT)

reset_btn = Button(
    frame3,
    text='Reset',
    command=fazer_reset
)
reset_btn.pack(side=LEFT)

sair_btn = Button(
    frame3,
    text='Sair',
    command=lambda: ws.destroy()
)
sair_btn.pack(side=RIGHT)

ws.mainloop()
```

The equation I use to calculate fat percentage is: fat percentage = (1.2 * IMC) + (0.23 * idade) -(10.8 * sexo) - 5.4. ‘IMC’ is BMI, ‘idade’ is age and ‘sexo’ is gender.

```
def calcular_gordura():
    idade = int(idade_tf.get())
    kg = int(peso_tf.get())
    m = int(altura_tf.get()) / 100
    imc = kg / (m * m)
    imc = round(imc, 1)
    gordura = (1.2*imc)+(0.23*idade)-(10.8*sexo)-5.4
    gordura = round(gordura, 1)
    percentual_de_gordura(gordura)
```

In ‘sexo’, I wanted the value assigned to be 1 if it’s male and 0 if it’s female.

The GUI I got uses two radio buttons: One for Masculino (Male) and one for Feminino (Female). But I’m not able to make them functional for the fat percentage equation.

```
masculino_rb = Radiobutton(
    frame2,
    text='Masculino',
    variable=var,
    value=1
)
masculino_rb.pack(side=LEFT)

feminino_rb = Radiobutton(
    frame2,
    text='Feminino',
    variable=var,
    value=0
)
feminino_rb.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

I tried to create an if and else condition, but I can't make the code understand the radio button selection.

Answer (score 1):

The radio button values are being assigned to the variable `var` in your example. However, you need to extract the value by using `var.get()`.
With this information in mind, you could set the `sexo` variable to be equal to `var.get()`.

```py
...

def calcular_gordura():
    sexo = var.get()
        
    idade = int(idade_tf.get())
    kg = int(peso_tf.get())
    m = int(altura_tf.get()) / 100
    imc = kg / (m * m)
    imc = round(imc, 1)
    gordura = (1.2*imc)+(0.23*idade)-(10.8*sexo)-5.4
    gordura = round(gordura, 1)
    percentual_de_gordura(gordura)

...
```